# When a post call doesn't return any response, do I need a reducer?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm wondering since my POST call doesn't give any data in response, do I need to have action types and reducer to maintain State?

This is my actioncreator. What will actionType and reducer contain?

```
export const postData = (...args) => async dispatch => {
    const [ url, body ] = args;
    const params = [ url, body, undefined, false, undefined , 'application/json'];
    try {
        const data = configs.ENV.DEVELOPMENT ? await API.getData(url, dispatch, actions, false) : await API.postData(params, dispatch, actions);
        if (!data) {
            window.location = configs.endpoints.RESULTS_PAGE;
        }
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.log('Please try again')
    } };
```

Comment: Usually you'd have state that represents the call itself (pending, fulfilled, rejected, etc.) even if it doesn't return any response, but I feel the answer to this would be opinionated since we know nothing about what you are trying to do.

Comment: if you need to somehow check this, for example, whether a post request was made

Comment: @chazsolo updated my post with actionCreator code

Comment: What you have is a _thunk_, not an action creator. It doesn't appear you are dispatching any actions at all (unless you are doing them in the methods of `API`, but I would recommend taking them out of there and dispatching actions within the thunk itself). I can't answer if you "need to have" something, that's up to you.

Comment: Yes, I'm having API methods as services